# How to do IIS SSL server redirects correctly? Is meta refresh needed?

Tags: iis, ssl, redirect

I think our backend programmer/server admin is handling our SSL redirects pretty wonky - see it in action here: [www.mchenry.edu/parentorientation](http://www.mchenry.edu/parentorientation)

1. First off, see how it redirects to
   index2.asp? Is this necessary? Can't
   she easily redirect to the original
   index.asp but have it be https://
   instead?
2. Also, she is using a meta refresh on
   the original index.asp page to
   redirect to index2.asp as well, and
   she says this is for backup, in case
   the server configs change and the
   server can't handle the redirect so
   then the webpage would take over.
3. Finally, she said she tried using
   the server redirect solely but that
   it kept looping on itself- what did
   she do wrong? Is this even possible?

Is she giving us a snow job or what?  I want a better understanding of what is happening here so I can talk to my boss about it, because this is driving me up the wall. Thanks for any info you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's basically a snow job. Install the IIS REdirect add-on. Setup a rule, match (.*) if {HTTPS} is `off` then redirect 301 to https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}. If you only want certain directories, then it gets a touch more complicated (but it's just regex, so nothing Earth shattering).

If it's looping then the server isn't checking for HTTPS being on/off. Meta-refresh is not a good idea in general, the page is sent unecrypted, and while it's probably just a redirect page, still not a good idea "in case the website changes". Sounds like she really doesn't know what she's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Pherhaps more of a question for [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)

I don't know the reason she did it that way but in classic ASP which you seem to use a redirect to SSL could be done like this:

[http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/tips/t010901-1.shtml](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131225/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/tips/t010901-1.shtml)

It should also be enough for your needs to just have the form go over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

We do a redirect to a HTTPS site purely in IIS.  We created an IIS entry for the non-secure site.  Under the Home Directory tab, we set up a permanent redirection to the https:// site.  Then, we set up a separate website entry on the same box, using a fake port 80 host header and the correct SSL-protected site.

```
So:
Site 1, http://website.com 
redirect (301)
Site 2, https:/website.com (also http://foobar)
```

Comment: That's one overly complicated way of doing it. You could also require SSL on the site, and setup a custom error page that redirect to the HTTPS version; that's a common hack.